# Battlefield 3's Battlelog doesn't recognize my Premium account

Tags: xbox-360, battlefield-3

On XBOX 360, I recently activated a BF3 Premium account.

Despite this, Battlelog keeps ignoring the fact that I own a Premium account and still shows that I should buy one (laugh):

[image: Get Premium Account]

I bought the Premium package on the XBOX Marketplace, I don't know at this point if this prevents Battlelog from showing it, but I formerly got Back To Karkand still from XBOX Marketplace, and that is recognized, as you can see:

[image]

I don't know how to activate it on Battlelog.

Comment: Can you use premium content on your console?

Comment: @SSumner: yes, I can use Premium content on my console.

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't cause any issue, but I remember having similar issues when I bought Premium for PC. Log out of battlelog, then log back in. For me, this solved the issue. Also, did you try to play at least one round on any new content? I could imagine the servers not syncing everything all the time and caching quite a lot of data.

Comment: It's been a month since I bought Premium subscription, and logged out and back in again many times, but the issue seems to persist.

Comment: Contact EA in that case: http://help.ea.com/